# Why my code still will return true?

Tags: javascript

Below is my code

```
test.map((value, index) => {
    console.log(value);
    if(value.customer_mobile) {
        alert(index + 'fail');
        return false;
    }

    if(value.customer_email) {
        alert(index + 'fail');
        return false;
    }
})

return true;
```

I run the code from above and it will return true even if `customer_mobile` is false. Why?

Comment: there is a typo after `fail` missing closing single quote.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the typo

Comment: `customer_mobile` => `value.customer_mobile` , I think it's property of the array element... share value of `test`

Comment: Now you modified the code, why do you not `console.log(customer_mobile)` ? - please post a [mcve]

Comment: I run the code from above and it will return true even if customer_mobile is false. Why?  if you set customer_mobile is false, it will never go inside the if condition

Comment: next time please show actual running code instead of incrementally update your question statement by statement. No-one coming after your will make sense of neither question nor answers to previous iterations

Comment: [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var flag = true;
test.map((value, index) => {
    console.log(value);
    if(customer_mobile) {
        alert(index + 'fail');
        flag = false;
    } 

    if(customer_email) {
        alert(index + 'fail');
        flag = false;
    }
});

return flag;
```

Comment: when using a flag, you should just use test.forEach, because you are not mapping test array for anything.

Answer (score 1):

Its not working because when you are using a Array.map which mapping your test array to a boolean array.

if you will assign it to a variable you will see you are getting something like

```
var temp = test.map((value,index)=> {
     /...
});
console.log(temp) // [false,false]
```

and then you just return true.

so you should first return true in the end of your map callback function. and then check the array coming back is all true.

```
return test.map((value, index) => {
    console.log(value);
    if(value.customer_mobile) {
        alert(index + 'fail');
        return false;
    }
    if(value.customer_email) {
        alert(index + 'fail');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}).every(bool => bool)
```